# Find all positive integer solutions of $(a,b,n)$ s.t. $(2^a-1)(2^b-1)=n^2$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

So recently I've received a problem (title) and I have no idea how to solve it. By easy observation, $(a,b)=(m,m),(6,3),(3,6)$ are the cases I've found, and no others.

So I try to let $kA^2=2^a-1$ and $kB^2=2^b-1$, where $k = \gcd(2^a-1,2^b-1)=2^{\gcd(a,b)}-1$. Then, another equation appears:$$\dfrac{2^a-1}{2^{\gcd(a,b)}-1}=A^2$$ the other one is similar. This expression is a bit ugly so I let $\gcd(a,b)=x$ , $a=xy$. The equation then becomes:
$$\dfrac{2^{xy}-1}{2^x-1}=A^2$$ which is much nicer. The solutions I have found for now (which is according to the (a,b) solutions above) are $(x,y)=(x,1),(3,2)$. Also, by modulus and some algebra, if there are more solutions we just found, then $x\ge3$ and $y\ge 5$. Well that's it. I can't go further more. Please give me some idea or even tips or solutions. Also, **no computer is allowed**. Thank you.

Comment: Isaac, There is a known fact that says Mersenne numbers which have the form $2^n-1$ can not be any power more than 1(including 2) of an integer. So you have to find common factors in two terms, like what you found $(63, 7)=7$.

Comment: [Zsigmondy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem) may be of interest (actually Bang's theorem, which is the special case with $a=2$ and $b=1$).

Comment: @Servaes I see. So it directly shows that $xy=6$ or $y=1$ in this case?

Comment: No; if $p$ divides $2^a-1$ but not $2^b-1$, then you might still get a solution if $p^2$ divides $2^a-1$. So this doesn't solve the problem yet, but does put strong restrictions on possible solutions.

Comment: I'm wondering whether you can use the fact that an odd square $\equiv 1 \bmod 8$.

Comment: @MarkBennet I have used it and ended with $x\ge3$