# How to solve Diophantine Equations $2^{4m}-1=(10k-5)^2$ and other similar ones?

Tags: number-theory, exponential-diophantine-equations

My motivation is my try for solving the following great question and then I stuck:

[Find all positive integer solutions of $(a,b,n)$ s.t. $(2^a-1)(2^b-1)=n^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3910928/find-all-positive-integer-solutions-of-a-b-n-s-t-2a-12b-1-n2)

so any variable in this question $\in \{1,2,3,...\}$

$(2^a-1)(2^b-1)=n^2$

first let $a=1$

then:

$(2-1)(2^b-1)=(2^b-1)=n^2$

If $n$ is positive integer then:

$ n \equiv 0,\pm1,\pm2   \pmod {5} $

then: $ n^{2} \equiv 0,1,4   \pmod {5} $

and

$ (2^{b}-1) \equiv 0   \pmod {5} $  when b=4m

$ (2^{b}-1) \equiv  1  \pmod {5} $  when b=4m-3

$ (2^{b}-1) \equiv  2  \pmod {5} $  when b=4m-1

$ (2^{b}-1) \equiv  3  \pmod {5} $  when b=4m-2

So probable solutions are when $b=4m,4m-3$

so I made the following equations:

First Case: let $b=4m, n=(10k-5)$ because  $n^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 5$ for all k

$2^{4m}-1=(10k-5)^2$

Second Case: let $b=4m-3,n=(10k-9)$  because $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ for all k

$2^{4m-3}-1=(10k-9)^2$

Third Case : let $b=4m-3,n=(10k-1)$  because $n^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 5$ for all k

$2^{4m-3}-1=(10k-1)^2$

*note that  $n=(10k-3)^2$ is included in Third Case: for example $n^2=((20-3)^2)^2=17^4=(280+9)^2$

Are there solutions or not ?

Comment: $\left(2^{2}-1\right)\left(2^{2}-1\right)=3^{2}$

Comment: @Mason Thank you but  I am trying to find solutions other than when $a=b$

Comment: The question in the title is trivial. The right side is a square, the left side is one less than a square, so you're asking for two squares to differ by one, and the only way that happens is for the squares to be zero and one.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you very much ... from you I know that one of the equations doesn't have solutions.

Comment: The other two cases, just look at them modulo eight.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you ...I tried an answer below ...please ...I want you to give your opinion about my solution.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending in comment by @Gerry Myerson ,many thanks for him.

For the first equation:

$2^{4m}-1=(10k-5)^2$ it turns out to be trivial because squares of integers can't differ by one.

For the second equation:

$2^{4m-3}-1=(10k-9)^2$

We will do it  by modulo $8$

If n is positive integer then:

$n \equiv 0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,4 \pmod 8$

then: $n^{2} \equiv 0,1,4 \pmod 8$

$(2^{4m-3}-1) \equiv 1 \pmod8$ for $m=1$

$(2^{4m-3}-1) \equiv 7  \pmod8$ for $m \in\{2,3,4,...\}$

so $m=1$ is probable

so the equation $2^{4m-3}-1=(10k-9)^2$ becomes $1=(10k-9)^2$ so k=1

then : $a=1=b,n=1$ which lies under the solution set $a=b$

Now for the third equation

$2^{4m-3}-1=(10k-1)^2$

we know from above that

$n^{2} \equiv 0,1,4 \pmod 8$

and

$(2^{4m-3}-1) \equiv 1 \pmod8$ for $m=1$

$(2^{4m-3}-1) \equiv 7  \pmod8$ for $m \in\{2,3,4,...\}$

so $m=1$ is probable

so the equation $2^{4m-3}-1=(10k-1)^2$ becomes $1=(10k-1)^2$ so there is no $k$ satisfies this equation since I assumed $k \in \{1,2,3,...\}$.